# What's the difference between 这本词典是老师的吗? and 这本是老师的词典吗?

Tags: grammar, difference, word-order

I wonder if there is a difference between these two sentences a) 这本词典是老师的吗? and b) 这本是老师的词典吗? Are they grammatically correct? thanks!

Comment: Same meaning with different emphasis, first on "词典", and second on "老师"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two sentences:

a) 这本词典是老师的吗?

b) 这本是老师的词典吗?

Are they grammatically correct?

I would suggest that you consider the third sentence:

c) 这本词典是老师的词典吗?

From (c), you can reduce either one of the words 词典 without introducing confusion. Therefore (a) and (b) are both grammatically correct.

Comment: In daily life, you can say, 这是老师的吗? when you finger point to the book and you believe that they can still understand you.

Answer (score 6):

a) 这本词典是老师的吗?

Is this dictionary the teacher's? Or more colloquially, Does this dictionary belong to the teacher?

这本是老师的词典吗?

Is this the teacher's dictionary?

They are both correct and mean essentially the same thing, except the first is slightly more emphatic on the dictionary.

Comment: No sure why the downvote? Any problem with the answer?

Answer (score 3):

[这本词典是老师的吗]意思是<这本词典>的主人是<老师>吗，[这本是老师的词典吗]把老师和词典变成了一个整体，也就是说第一句是对<老师>这一个词表示疑问，第二句是对<老师的词典>这一个整体发问
但是我觉得第二句说起来有点怪怪的…

Answer (score 0):

Both versions are correct. They both mean the same thing.